# Storing multidimensional Data that can be accessed by Key VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel, data-structures

I need a data structure in VBA that will allow me to use a for loop to iterate over a list of investments and store them by "investment name" and then store both the "Market Value" and "Percent Return" paired with that "investment name". I was imagining a dictionary of arrays but read that VBA dictionaries are not allowed to contain arrays. I was hoping to be able to call investmentDictionary.item("investment name")(0 or 1) = 0 would be Market Value and 1 would be Percent Return.

It is very important that I can access by dictionary keys because I will be updating data on a spreadsheet that is constantly changing in dimension so I cannot rely on index numbers. I am not very experienced with coding in general so I would appreciate an example of the specific syntax involved. I also know that I can complete this task with a multi-dimensional array in which I iterate over the first dimension to find the name but I am wondering how efficient this would be compared to a dictionary method. I would appreciate any insights.

--Drake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you properly then is this what you want

```
  Dim dict As Object


  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  'create an array with the number of values you want to add to a specific key. You can do it in a loop as well'
  a = Array("Market_Value", "Percent_Return", "Whatever")

  'add the values to the key'
  If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
      dict.Add "investment name", a
  End If

 For Each Key In dict
     'returns investment name'
     MsgBox Key

     'returns Market Value, Percent Return, Whatever'
     MsgBox Join(dict.Item(Key))

     'if you want to access the inner elements of the value list'
      b = Split(Join(dict.Item(Key)), " ")

      'returns Market_Value'
      MsgBox b(0)


      'returns Percent_Return'
       MsgBox b(1)
 Next Key
```

If that's what you are looking for don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I may have worded the question poorly though. I see that your example would allow me to access the "return" with "Market Value" as the key. What if the "market value" is unknown and I need to use investment name to access both "market value" and "return"? The issue arises from pairing two items to a single key.

Comment: I have changed my code. Please have a look and let me know